# Microk8s Cluster Node not ready on Ubuntu with "cni plugin not initialized: failed to load cni config"

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu

I'm trying to start a microk8s kubernetes instance on an ubuntu server, however the node becomes not ready.

```
~$ microk8s status
microk8s is not running. Use microk8s inspect for a deeper inspection.
```

Inspect returns the following error message:

```
less /var/snap/microk8s/6103/inspection-report/snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd/journal.log
  level=error msg="failed to load cni during init, please check CRI plugin status before setting up network for pods" error="cni config load fa
    iled: no network config found in /var/snap/microk8s/6103/args/cni-network: cni plugin not initialized: failed to load cni config"
```

The node is stuck with a similar message:

```
microk8s kubectl describe node
Name:               xxx
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=xxx
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    microk8s.io/cluster=true
                    node.kubernetes.io/microk8s-controlplane=microk8s-controlplane
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Wed, 08 Nov 2023 08:42:48 +0000
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  xxx
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Wed, 08 Nov 2023 09:19:13 +0000
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Wed, 08 Nov 2023 09:15:07 +0000   Wed, 08 Nov 2023 08:42:48 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Wed, 08 Nov 2023 09:15:07 +0000   Wed, 08 Nov 2023 08:42:48 +0000   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Wed, 08 Nov 2023 09:15:07 +0000   Wed, 08 Nov 2023 08:42:48 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            False   Wed, 08 Nov 2023 09:15:07 +0000   Wed, 08 Nov 2023 08:42:48 +0000   KubeletNotReady              container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized
```

Since it seems potentially relevant: The host is behind a corporate proxy with no internes access except for the proxy configured in /etc/environment:

```
http_proxy=http://xxx:3128/
https_proxy=http://xxx:3128/
no_proxy=10.0.0.0/8,192.168.0.0/16,127.0.0.1,172.16.0.0/16
```

Could anyone explain what the problem in this case is?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS EKS, you need to install CNI Plugin.

Also, could you please share the output of sudo microk8s inspect

Comment: I'm not using AWS EKS; this is running on an ubuntu cloud image hosted by a provider.